# Focus on input / textareas in bootstrap modal stolen when AJAX request made in background

Tags: jquery, ajax, input, focus, bootstrap-modal

I have a very specific problem when displaying a bootstrap modal that contains text inputs or textareas. This only occurs in Google Chrome. Firefox and Edge are fine.

When one of these inputs or textareas has focus, and a jQuery AJAX request is made in the background, the focus on the input or the textarea is lost. This only occurs when the input or textarea is in a bootstrap modal. Any other inputs or textareas on the site are fine when the background AJAX request is made.

Please see: http://www.lambwatch.co.uk and click on the "Register" button in the top right. A modal appears. Now click on any input field and wait a few seconds for the background AJAX request to fire, and the focus on the input is lost. This only occurs in Chrome. Firefox and Edge are fine.

The background AJAX request is a basic one and runs every 7 seconds.

```
$.post("/json-page.htm",{"pp":10},function(json)
{
    // do something
},"json");
```

Comment: This bug is not in every chrome browser but many of them are having this issue.

Comment: In my case the issue got resolved when I opened Chrome in Private Browsing (Private Browser). I am not sure how this happened but works for me.